# java do while missing return statement

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

I have a method, it hints that the return statement is missing, but I don’t think the statement `return -1` will be executed. Can anybody tell me why?

```
private int loop() {
    int retryTimes = 2;
    do {
        try {
            // simulate real business
            int value = new Random().nextInt(3);
            if (value % 3 != 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            return value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (retryTimes <= 0) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    } while (retryTimes-- > 0);
    // if below line not exists; prompt error: missing return statement
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: It's just because the compiler is not able to detect that it will never reach this line

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler suspects that should the `while` loop iterate more than 2 times, that line with the `return -1` would be reached.  And, should there not a be a `return` statement there, then it would be a problem.

That your actual code's logic doesn't necessarily allow for this doesn't matter to the compiler.  There can always be unexpected exceptions, so you should rightfully have a catch-all return statement at the end of the method, outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the return statement inside the catch block like this since you are returning a value on the successful execution, you also need to return a value on failure.

```
     private int loop() {
        int retryTimes = 2;
        do {
            try {
                // simulate real business
                int value = new Random().nextInt(3);
                if (value % 3 != 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
                return value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (retryTimes <= 0) {
                    throw e;
                }
                return -1;
            }
        } while (retryTimes-- > 0);
    }
```